# Watching feeds from multiple endoscope OTG cameras simultaneously

Tags: camera

I bought a 10m cable long Android and PC Endoscope camera with LED light, and I would like to buy more endoscope cameras to watch twin or quad live video on Android tablet.

In theory this encoscope camera is supported in PC but fails to work on Windows XP (32-bit) (file nusb3hub.sys is missing)

There is a large number of encoscope camera apps available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=an100&c=apps&authuser), but I need to install 2 or 4 encoscope usb cameras via OTG hub to work in parallel

I am aware of USB 2.0 limitations, since under Windows XP (32-bit)  I can, in theory, connect up to 8 cameras to my PC, 2 cameras for every usb interface card and watch 8 video streams in HTML.

So what can I do to watch feeds from supported 2 or 4 encoscope usb cameras?

Note: http://www.kkmoom.com/pc.rar
is a link to download PC driver for PC endoscope usb camera
(file nusb3hub.sys is missing in case of my old PC mainboard).

Comment: I imagine that nusb3hub stands for USB 3.0 Driver & port... Try to find a USB 3.0 driver for XP ? ... .. You might be able to use wireless cameras, if that's any help.... This developer has built support for 2 cameras simultaneously https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=infinitegra.app.usbcamera

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I have installed my camera since missing  nusb3hub standing for USB 3.0 Driver & port has been installed earlier with my USB 3.0 extension card, placed into another directory.
I hope to buy 4 endoscope cameras this week for tests.
Good point since endoscope camera is not described as USB 3.0 device in manual (none available), so I need to use USB 3.0 slot in  my PC.

I need to check which smartphones support USB 3.0 OTG port to run more tests to get HD resolution as claimed by a manufacturer.
The issue is 10m  long cable is not supported  by USB standard